# Is there any way to trigger an exception for incorrect string inputs in Python?

Tags: python, try-catch

I am creating a text-to-speech synthesizer in Python. To allow maximum flexibility and user-friendliness, the program allows the user to edit variables, like speech rate or volume. I made a try-except-else loop to catch any wrong inputs. The problem with this is that the if an input is invalid, the exception is not triggered until later in the program. The inputs that are not being caught are strings. Is there any way to trigger an exception if certain keywords are **not** inputted, like:

```
while True:
    try:
        var = input("Choose your speech rate (Slow, Normal, or Fast): ")
    except var != "Slow", "Normal", "Fast" :
        print("\nPlease try again.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to raise an exception. Just use an `if/else` statement instead.

Also, to check if `var` is either one of `Slow`, `Normal` or `Fast`, check it's membership on a set with those elements using the [`in`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) keyword:

```py
while True:
    var = input("Choose your speech rate (Slow, Normal, or Fast): ")
    
    if var not in {"Slow", "Normal", "Fast"}:
        print("\nPlease try again.")
    else:
        break
```